# How can I print Json values in a gridview?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, xamarin, gridview

I am trying to print values from a Json string in a gridview with C# using Visual Studio 2017. The problem is that I can't get the specific Value to a single word.
Here is my code:

```
string link = @"http://alexander.*************/test.php";
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(link);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

I want to print both Values from "Name" in the gridview, but how?
The Names has to put in this Item list:

```
myItems = (array?);
string test2 = test1.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, myItems);
GridviewCoins.Adapter = adapter;
```

And finally the json string is:

```
{
    "Coins": [[{
        "Name": "007",
        "Id": "5294",
    }], [{
        "Name": "1337",
        "Id": "20824",
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple problems here, first is that your Coins Property is an array of arrays, and that you jsonObject is not complete it should look like :

"{ "Coins": [[{ "Name": "007", "Id": "5294", } ], [{ "Name": "1337", "Id": "20824", }]]}";

That said if this is a copy paste error I would do some thing like:

```
 public IEnumerable<Coin> GetCoins(string json)
 {
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var coinPropery = jObject["Coins"] as JArray;

        var coins = new List<Coin>();

        foreach (var property in coinPropery)
        {
            var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(property.ToString());
            coins.AddRange(propertyList);
        }

        return coins;
 }
```

and the coin object:

```
public class Coin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

when then you have a c# object and you can do what ever you want with it.

**EDIT:**
You can add to gridview by following [Click here](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/create-a-gridview-with-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond! My bad... It was a Copy/Paste error, but when the Coin info is listed, how can I print the Name in a Gridview???

Comment: I have added a link

Comment: One other thing... Your code works great, but I called my GridView: "GridviewCoins". But I can't use GridviewCoins.DataSource. Because it says that Gridview doesn't contains a defenition for DataSource. What can I do???